# Understanding the complex relationship between macro and micro economic factor: Job shift

Tags: unemployment, open-economy-macro, usa, china

As the world knows plenty of manufacturing jobs shifted from various countries to China. This macroeconomic trend of consolidating manufacturing jobs in China has been going on for past 30 years. Please help me understand given that so many jobs have been moved out of countries like US, why there has not been significant reduction in the demand and spending of the people in these countries. As per my understanding if people start loosing their job, they start spending less and less eventually slowing down entire economy of a country. How are countries still not affected by such a massive out flux of jobs?